# "Module parse failed: Unexpected token" in dependence package when use import image

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue-cli, babel-loader, npm-package

I was wrote package with use typescript, webpack and babel. Project build three.js scene with textures from public folder. And it's work fine.

Then I was npm publish package, and install this in other project(vue-cli 3). And it's work fine, but texture wasn't load.

I return to my first project, move my texture from public to src/assets, import this by "import MyTexture from './assets/myTexture.png'". Checked it with webpack dev server. It's work fine.

Then I update packet with npm publish

I was go to other project, reinstall my packet and take this error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:58761) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

**My packet configs:**

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        clean: true,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        library: {
            type: 'module',
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg|woff|ttf|wav|mp3)$/,
                type: 'asset',
                generator: {
                    filename: '[hash][ext][query]',
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __PRODUCTION__: JSON.stringify(true),
        }),
    ],
    performance: {
        maxEntrypointSize: 1024000,
        maxAssetSize: 1024000,
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
    },
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
};
```

tsconfig:

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/types",
    "lib": ["esnext", "es2017", "es7", "es6", "dom"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "strict": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
  },
  "paths": {
    "@/*": [
      "src/*"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.19.17",
 
  "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "module": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.17.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.cjs",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.dev.cjs",
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/*",
    "public/*"
  ],
  "types": "./dist/bundle.d.ts",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^18.6.4",
    "platform": "^1.3.6",
    "three": "^0.132.2",
    "troika-three-text": "^0.46.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.18.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "@types/three": "^0.134.0",
    "@types/tweenjs": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.27.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.27.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "ts-mixer": "^6.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "webpack": "^5.52.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

**Other project config**

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "paren-package",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8081",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apidevtools/swagger-parser": "^10.0.3",
    "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^18.6.4",
    "@types/three": "^0.134.0",
    "@types/tweenjs": "^1.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-extensions": "^3.1.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dat.gui": "^0.7.7",
    "my-package": "^1.19.17",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "jsonata": "^1.8.6",
    "jsoneditor": "^9.5.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "platform": "^1.3.6",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1",
    "three": "^0.132.2",
    "troika-three-text": "^0.42.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "v-clipboard": "^2.2.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-json-pretty": "^1.8.1",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-typed-mixins": "^0.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "n8n-workflow": "~0.62.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

webpack config: vue-cli 3 default setting